# How can I hide a table in a particular database?

Tags: security, sql-server-2008

In my database I have a table called Price.

I want to hide this table.  Is this possible ?

Comment: Hide it from whom?   A user in enterprise manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user does not have `SELECT` permissions on the table then they will not be able view the table in Object Explorer.

i.e.

```
deny select on TableToHide to UserThatShouldntSeeTable
go
```

Comment: didnt work for me. After running the command, I got the message "Command(s) completed successfully", but the table is still visible in Obj Explorer (even after refresh).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your particular circumstances, you may be able to use the Tables "filter" functionality. You can filter your list of tables in the Obj Explorer to view only those tables that satisfy certain criteria. (Unfortunately, you cannot HIDE certain tables, you can only SHOW certain tables, while hiding all others.)

To do this, simply r-click on the "Tables" node, and select Filter -> Filter Settings. This opens a dialog which allows you to specify the criteria (name, owner, date of creation, etc) by which you want to specify which tables should be visible. More details can be found in [this post](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/77/posts/11276/filtering-within-object-explorer-underappreciated-features-of-microsoft-sql-server.aspx).

It's too bad you can't save filters (based on schemas, for example), but at least it's a start.

[Now *if only* we could [do the same thing with the list of Databases](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/273830/need-view-definition-permissions-per-database) on shared servers...!]